# Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryCache.EF6 Requires QueryDeferred Library?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

When trying to use the QueryCache library to do some L2 caching of a few entities, I am receiving a compiler error on .FromCache() indicating the QueryDeferred library is required. Documentation indicates QueryCache can be used as stand-alone.

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;

namespace LookupValuesMap.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            LookupValueContext ctx = new LookupValueContext();
            var companies = ctx.Companies.FromCache().ToList();  <-- error
```

Here is the error:

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'QueryDeferred<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryDeferred.EF6, Version=1.6.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=59b66d028979105b'.
```

Thank you in advance!

J Kent

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Due to how the library has been built, some "standalone" features like this one may have the Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryDeferred.EF6 requirement.

You can download the version from: [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryDeferred.EF6/)

We will eventually fix it for no longer having to have this dependence.